# Search English word (ex: "carve" in Hebrew) and return each occurrence in The Bible

Tags: discussion

1. I want to type in "carve" and show everywhere that Hebrew term appears in The Bible.  Any websites do this?  2)  Also, where can I open the concordance and simply scroll down the words listing?  Thank you

Comment: See https://biblescan.com/searchot.php?q=carve

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.